# When not logged in, clicking Run Query navigates to the raw text result rather than showing the result on the same page

Tags: bug, data-explorer

Lately, clicking Run Query on any Data Explorer query (where the result wasn't generated beforehand) navigates to URLs like `data.stackexchange.com/query/run/1/*/*`, usually with the JSON query result, rather than showing a reCaptcha challenge (as it usually would). This issue occurs only when I am not logged in. I think this is a recent issue, as I did see a reCaptcha challenge the first time I used the Data Explorer within the last hour.

---

As of March 18, 2016, this issue still seems to occur occasionally, and this 
time the result can be text saying `{"captcha": true}`, as I recall, rather than
the JSON query result. If it's relevant, I use the Firefox browser.

Comment: Someone mentioned this before but I was never able to reproduce it. In case it turns out to be relevant, what browser are you using?

Comment: @Tim just happened to me now, it happens when the connection is very slow or broken, so required JS resources are not loaded. Maybe worth disabling the button, and enabling it with JS once it's fully loaded? What do you think?